# Express.js 'app' in one line instead of two

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

When using Express I always have to do this.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Alternatively to make it a little more cohesive I sometimes do this.

```js
const
  express = require('express'),
  app = express();
```

Is there a way to write this in one line instead of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using es6 it is easy: `const[<variable declarations>] = [<require modules>]`

```js
const [app = express()] = [require('express')];
```

This type of syntactic sugar is what make ES6 JavaScript really amazing.

If I wanted to add more modules like `fs` and `path` and it can be destructured to expose the methods so you dont have always type `fs` or `path` before you can use an attached method.

```js
const [fs,path,app=express()] = [require('fs'), require('path'), require('express')]
```

Now I have declared what is usually 4 lines in only 1 line.

It can go even further by using destructuring, for example I want to read files async and that usually requires `fs` methods and `path` methods.

```js
const [{readFileSync},{resolve,join},app=express()] = [require('fs'), require('path'), require('express')]
```

So eventually it becomes kinda sloppy and to bring sanity back place line breaks.

```js
const [
  {readFileSync},
  {resolve,join},
  app=express()
] = [require('fs'), require('path'), require('express')]
```

And now you can streamline your code even further by the magic of `es6`.

```js
const [
  {readFileSync: read, writeFileSync: write},
  {resolve,join},
  app=express()
] = [require('fs'), require('path'), require('express')]
```

In this scenario I now only have to call `read` instead of `readFileSync` and `write` instead of `writeFileSync`.

Comment: This is one of those *"just because you can, doesn't mean you should"*.

Comment: The great thing about unopinionated language like js is that there is no such thing as I shouldn't. I have the freedom to do whatever I want. In the practical monolithic sense, this won't be useful. And if you are only used to writing monoliths with the express, then reading the above is wasting your time. But express is so much more than just one thing, it could only be used as a quick no-nonsense page server using read stream-pipe-to-write stream response, or a microservice running in a container. I believe in clean code and collaboration. Use it, or don't. The choice is yours.

Comment: I'm certainly on board with "clean code and collaboration", but unconventional code like this this is unclean and makes it harder to collaborate. You've ended up with something that's hard to follow and uses *more* lines; even if I agreed that saving vertical space should be a goal, you've missed it. And sure you can use Express (or... imports, I guess?) for many things, but that's totally orthogonal to the discussion here and it's not clear why you think that's a justification. Sure it's a choice, but someone impressionable and inexperienced might make the wrong one.

Comment: And to be clear for those people - the object destructuring and aliasing for each import is fine, it's the array destructuring across all of the imports that makes it harder to read, reuse and refactor.

Comment: Sure you can use imports but that requires configuration. The code is definitely not unconventional because the spec for it is published by a standards board (ECMA). Being concise is a principle of writing clean code, I am for sure not writing more code by using the latest es6 features. To add to this I don't decide what is good coding practice or not, That is my linters job. Destructuring and aliasing is the refactoring part, and I have created great reuse components in application domains that help me and my team implement way faster and we ensure continuity by documentation.

Comment: All of the above is your opinion and that is your right, to iterate once more JS is an unopinionated programming language.

Comment: Also, thinking about it I realised this just doesn't work. In `const [foo = bar] = [...]` the default value `bar` is only evaluated when the first element in the array is `undefined`, e.g. when the array is empty. `app` will still be `require("express")` (unless that leads to `undefined`, in which case it'll cause a reference error). Also note that a specification is not the same thing as a convention.